# class property set to default after redirection

Tags: php

I have this `public static login()` method in `class Member` and  `static $logged  = false` as a default value.
When login data comes through method to be checked `$logged` should be changed to `true` and redirected to the profile page.
But on  profile.php  `$logged = false`back to default value.
What I'm missing?

```
class Member
{


public static $logged = false;


public static function logIn($data)
{
    global $db;
    global $messages;

    //$dataChecked = self::filterData($data);
    $user = $db->fetch("select * from gym_members where email = :email",['email'=>$dataChecked['email']]);
    if ($user&&$user->status>"0") 
    {

        if ($data['pass'] == $user->password) 
        {

                $_SESSION['id'] = $user->id;
                self::$logged = true;
                header("Location:profile.php");

        }
        else
        {
            header("Location:login.php");
            $messages = 'incorrect password';
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        header("Location:login.php");
        $messages = "User not found";
    }


}
```

Comment: `static`s don't persist across multiple requests. That's not what they're for.

Comment: so I should change `$logged` property?

Comment: You should create a method to check if a user is logged in by checking  the session and clear out session on logout. That is the normal way to create login functionality